# In PHP, how can we define a field as a certian class's instance like JAVA?

Tags: php

Then I can use the auto-completion in an IDE.

In `Java` we define a class like

```
class AppleTree{
    Apple apple;
}

class Apple {
    Color getColor() {}
}
```

So when I input `apple.`, the IDE can bring out a list that contains `getColor()` method.

In `PHP` we can define a class like

```
class AppleTree
{
    public $apple;
}

class Apple
{
     public function getColor() {}
}
```

Comment: Your chosen ide would have to support that...

Comment: In PHP like Ruby the typeof is defined by own language, you dont need to declare type its own read and declared by PHP

Comment: To make sense of what Alvaro said... You don't need to type cast, you only instantiate your variable as what you want it to be. I know there are some php preprocessors and ides that will handle that for you but now you have enough information to google it yourself

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón What I am aiming for is the auto-completion.

Comment: @ElefantPhace Actually I tried to type cast the variable to a certain Class but failed. Seems PHP doesn't support that.

Comment: That's exactly what I said...  It doesn't, but there are preprocessors that do and ides that do. But your question was too lacking to provide a specific answer unlike the given one that actually suggest one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is auto-completion you can go with DocBlocks.

```
class AppleTree
{
    /**
     * @var Apple
     */
    public $apple;
}

class Apple
{
    /**
     * @return Color
     */
    public function getColor() {}
}
```

However if you want to achieve the behavior that restricts setting anything but instances of given class you have to use type hinting e.g.

```
class AppleTree
{
    /**
     * @var Apple
     */
    protected $apple;

    public function setApple(Apple $apple)
    {
        $this->apple = $apple;
    }

    /**
     * @return Apple
     */
    public function getApple()
    {
        return $this->apple;
    }
}
```